# Codeigniter : displaying query result in controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to display my db query result in my controller, but I don't know how to do it. could you please show me?

Controller

```
 function get_name($id){

 $this->load->model('mod_names');
 $data['records']=$this->mod_names->profile($id);

// I want to display the the query result here 
 // like this:  echo $row ['full_name'];

 }
```

My Model

```
function profile($id)
    {  

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('names');
        $this->db->where('id', $id); 
        $query = $this->db->get();


        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        { return $query->row_array();
        }
        else {return NULL;}

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data['records']);
```

or

```
 echo $data['records'][0]['fullname'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried `echo $data['records'][0]['fullname'];` But I get this message: Undefined offset: 0 Thanks :)

Comment: ok change it like this it will work fine echo $data['records']['fullname'];

Answer (score 4):

Model:

```
function profile($id){  
    return $this->db->
    select('*')->
    from('names')->
    where('id', $id)->
    get()->row_array();
}
```

Controller:

```
function get_name($id){

    $this->load->model('mod_names');
    $data['records']=$this->mod_names->profile($id);

    print_r($data['records']); //All 
    echo $data['records']['full_name']; // Field name full_name

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do that inside a View, like this.

Controller:

```
 function get_name($id){

    $this->load->model('mod_names');
    $data['records']=$this->mod_names->profile($id);
    $this->load->view('mod_names_view', $data); // load the view with the $data variable

 }
```

View (mod_names_view):

```
 <?php foreach($records->result() as $record): ?>
     <?php echo $record->full_name); ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I would modify your model then to something like this (it worked for me):

```
function profile($id)
{  
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('names');
    $this->db->where('id', $id); 
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
     return $query; // just return $query
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know how to do it in the view file. But I need to get the query result in my controller. Thanks :)