# Codeigniter: Severity notice Message Array to String conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to this and failed to understand why this is happening. I am getting result from database they are:

```
ArrayArray ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [box] => draggable1 [xorder] => 1 [descp] => Y ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [box] => draggable2 [xorder] => 2 [descp] => Z ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [box] => draggable3 [xorder] => 3 [descp] => X ) )
```

I am  trying to print single value such as printing only `id value 1` or `box value draggable1` from list of array. But problem is when i apply

```
echo $result1['data'];
```

**gives error:**

```
Severity: Notice
Message Array to String conversion
```

similarly while further trying by doing:

```
echo $result1['data']['id']; //id is field name
```

**gives me error:**

```
undefined index : id
```

and lastly when i got tired did this:

```
print_r($result1['data'][0]);
```

and **printed the result**

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [box] => draggable1 [xorder] => 1 [descp] => Y )
```

but when i do so:

```
print_r($result1['data'][0]['id']);
```

**gives error:**

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

i follow this post which is related to me but i dont know why i am unable to do so [Codeigniter : displaying query result in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684329/codeigniter-displaying-query-result-in-controller)

Here is my function:

```
public function index()
    {
        $id=$this->input->post('name');
        $result1['data']=$this->drag_model->getcoordinates();
        $result2['data']=$this->drag_model->getva($id);

        echo $result1['data']['id'];
        print_r($result1['data'][0]['id']);
    //  array('id'=>);
        //  $this->load->view('drag/drag_view');
        $this->load->view('drag/dragswap',$result1);

    //  $this->load->view('LoginN/login_view');

    }
```

Comment: Rizier123 i ve already mentioned the reason and at the below i ve mentioned my closest post but i went fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last error message got you where you need to be, but you're trying to use an object as an array. Objects are referenced like this:

```
$result1['data'][0]->id
```

Comment: thanks man. This tired me alot. (y)